# Check if values are valid before create()

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

Hi I'm trying to import lines from a CSV, but I can't handle type errors.
For example, if you insert a string in a datetime field, I get this error in the create:

```
psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Despite handling errors with

```py
try:
  my_module.create()
exception Except:
  #stuff
  pass
```

How can I check the values before I get to create or at least handle the error and take other actions. For the moment if I insert a field that is not present on a selection, I manage with try catch but I can't for data types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method `load(fields, data)` on `BaseModel` which you could extend.

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # if a new model
    _name = 'my.model'
    # if an extended model
    #  _inherit = 'my.model'

    def load(self, fields, data):
    """ Extended to do stuff to the data before importing it to database"""
        # do stuff like converting weird data input
        clean_data = self.clean_data(data)
        # call super with cleaned data afterwards
        return super(MyClass, self).load(fields, clean_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually can, for data types. Even though I don't really understand your code, you can explicitly cast a variable to a certain datatype and then catch the ValueError exception in that specific cast fail, like this:

```
  try:
    int(variable)
  except ValueError:
    print("Variable was not an integer.")
```

Comment: vals is a dict {'name":"Marco", "birth_date":"CIAO",....} ok? in create i pass vals, but the problem,  I can't manage errors on writing fields, especially when they are of different types.

Comment: Then check dict values for errors in matching the needed datatype before passing vals to create. If you know for example that the value associated with birth_date key must be a datetime object, check if it actually is by casting it and catching the eventual exception.